How to reverse a NumPy array using stride_tricks.as_strided
Is it possible to reverse an array using as_strided in NumPy? I tried the following and got garbage results
Note : I am aware of indexing tricks like ::-1, but what to know if this can be achieved thru ax_strided.
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


elems = 16
inp_arr = np.arange(elems).astype(np.int8)

print(inp_arr)
print(inp_arr.shape)
print(inp_arr.strides)

expanded_input = as_strided(inp_arr[15],
                            shape = inp_arr.shape,
                            strides = (-1,))
print(expanded_input)
print(expanded_input.shape)
print(expanded_input.strides)

Output
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
(16,)
(1,)
[  15 -113    0   21   -4 -119  -53    3   79    0    0    0    0    0
0    2]
(16,)
(-1,)

Do the indexed reverse that you know, and examine its strides.  Then see if you can setup the same thing with as_strided.  Also why do you want to do this?  ::-1 indexing makes a view, and may be faster. as_strided also makes a view, but seems to have a higher setup cost.

@hpaulj when reversed using index, it did show stride as -1.

Change inp_arr[-1:], you are referencing a value not the array.

@MichaelSzczesny - thanks it worked. Can you post it as answer so I can mark is as accepted answer.

Indeed you can reverse an array using as_strided() (notwithstanding the question of whether you should); however, one has to get both the strides and the array offset correct:

In the 1-dimensional case, one has to

start from the last element and
negate the stride (which, for an 8-bit/1-byte data type, is the same as setting it to -1).


Generally, in the N-dimensional case of an arbitrary data type, one has to

start from the last element in the axis of interest and
negate the stride in the axis of interest.



See code below, where r_1d and r_nd are exemplary results of reversing with as_strided():
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

# 1D, 8-bit/1-byte dtype: (1) start from last element, (2) set stride == -1
a_1d = np.arange(16, dtype=np.int8)
r_1d = as_strided(a_1d[-1:], shape=a_1d.shape, strides=(-1, ))
assert (r_1d == a_1d[::-1]).all()

# ND, arbitrary dtype: (1) start from last element in axis of interest, (2)
# negate stride in axis of interest (below, axis of interest is axis 1)
a_nd = np.arange(2*3*5, dtype=float).reshape(2, 3, 5)
a_offset = a_nd[:, -1:]
r_strides = np.multiply([1, -1, 1], a_nd.strides)
r_nd = as_strided(a_offset, shape=a_nd.shape, strides=r_strides)
assert (r_nd == a_nd[:, ::-1]).all()

As a cautionary note, I should add that I only tried with contiguous arrays (both C and F), others might require more effort.

Got it. I made a mistake in selecting the last element while posting question.
